# Relative Interior of a Convex Hull

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Given pts $y_0,...,y_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$, their convex hull is Co($y_0,...,y_k$):={$\sum_{i=0}^k a_i y_i$ : each $a_i \geq 0$, $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i =1$}.  
Their affine hull is Aff($y_0,...,y_k$):={$\sum_{i=0}^k a_i y_i$ :  $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i =1$}
Given A$\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, its relative interior is ri(A):={$y\in A$ : $\exists r>0$ s.t. B(y,r)$\cap$Aff($y_0,...,y_k$)$\subseteq$A} 
(Here B(y,r):={x$\in \mathbb{R}^n$ : $||x-y||_2<$r} )
I'd like to show ri(Co($y_0,...,y_k$))={$\sum_{i=0}^k a_i y_i$ : each $a_i > 0$, $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i =1$}. (1)
I think I can show "$\subseteq$" if I also assume $y_0,...,y_k$  are affinely independent (means $y_1 -y_0,...,y_k -y_0$ are linearly independent), for then each y$\in$Aff($y_0,...,y_k$) can be uniquely written $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i y_i$, where  $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i =1$. 
However, when I considered some examples, it seems (1) also holds w/o assuming  affinely independent.

Comment: You have separation theorems?

Comment: No I don't.  Can you give an example?

Comment: To prove $\subset$: you take a point from the relative interior, it can be written as a convex combination of some independent (basic) $y_j$ with $\alpha_j>0$. Now you can add all other $y_i$ with very small $\epsilon>0$ and compensate this addition using the basic $y_j$. Since $\alpha_j>0$ a small change will keep the strict inequality. So you get all $\alpha>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, let $y_0$ be the origin. If the vectors are not affinely independent, they all belong to a linear subspace $S$ of lower dimension $m$. Taking $m$ as small as possible, the vectors are affinely independent in $S$.You can then replace "B(y,r)" in the def'n of ri(A) with the ball B(y,r) of the space $S$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your logic?  I don't think vectors can't be made linearly independent by considering a smaller space.  For instance, $(0,1)^T$ and $(0,2)^T$ aren't linearly independent in any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: yes you are right..I dk what I meant . I was considering induction on the dimension n.I dk if that would work.